# Django mod-wsgi multiple instances of One Class object

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am currently using a DJango - apache installation (on mod_wsgi) to run a website (project) which hosts an intranet cards game, whose rules are complicated enogh that it requires only 1 master list+dict data structure of scores for each user. Individual user's score can be impacted by other users actions also. I am using a Score class which I instantiate in urls.py and all players / users access this class' object [scObj = Scorer('Spades') ]. internally in this obj there are Dicts of players actions, score updates etc etc.

```
    class Scorer:
        def __init__(self, suitname):
            self.__suitname = suitname
```

The scorer class is separately stored in Scorer.py

```
    scObjs = (Scorer('Spades'), Scorer('Hearts'), Scorer('Clubs'), Scorer('Diamonds'),)
```

The objects are created in urls.py

This model was running perfectly in the DEV deployement. When I moved to PROD in apache, this broke (as in there are multiple instances of scObj being created, so a score update from player-1's move on player-2 is not reflected in a different move by player-3 on player-2) . I need to simulate a singleton class behaviour / global scObj behaviour, which I am not able to do. I am running apache in worker - mpm - multithreaded mode, so I assume that the problem of multiple copies of scObj being there due to multi-process is not there.

Is the problem related to mod_wsgi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

Using embedded mode, whether it be worker MPM or prefork MPM on UNIX systems will be multi process.

Use daemon mode and the default of a single process and you should be okay.

See notes at end of that documentation though about using proper database storage if necessary. Also heed warnings about multithread access to data and make code thread safe.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this. I do remeber reading something in your post about mod_python that we should use django worker mpm in embed mode, probably missed it during the installation.

Comment: Daemon mode is preferred, not embedded. If you must use embedded mode for some reason then worker is preferred over prefork MPM. http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Comment: Sorry. I meant I read about daemon mode in your post about mod_python memory spikes. Then I was using mod_py and just wanted to clarify which to use in apache (worker vs prefork). Did give much thought to the statement "embed in wsgi will result in same problems as above" at that time. Anyways, now using daemon mode, we have a single instance of Scores and everything is fine. Thanks a lot.